# Xcode Conditional Compilation of Shared Framework Based on Target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iOS app with a few today extensions and Siri shortcut targets. In order to share common code between them, I've also created a framework. I'm trying to integrate Firebase network performance monitoring into my shared framework but am running into a problem when trying to compile the extension targets as Firebase calls `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` which isn't available for extension targets. I'm mostly concerned with monitoring network performance in the actual app so I don't care if it's disabled for the extensions. Is there a way to achieve this?

I thought I could achieve it by defining a macro as part of the app target's `Other C Flags` and then checking if that macro is defined in the framework but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Macros are defined as "Preprocessor".. not "C Flags".. `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` So that's why you stuff didn't work.  Example: `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS= $(inherited) -DMyFlagHere=1`

Comment: I tried that as well. Are frameworks compiled for each target, or is it compiled once and then just linked to each?

Comment: Each "configuration" will be compiled.. You can compile specifically for extensions by adding a new target to the framework no?

Comment: The framework is a dependency of each extension, not the other way around, so I don't think the extensions can be targets for it. Maybe what I want to do isn't possible